# jQuery - auto-expanding textarea doesn't handle pasted input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to auto-expand/shrink a textarea based on the entered text. The textarea has a specified height of `250px`, and can auto-expand up to `450px` before `overfow: auto` kicks in with a scrollbar. It works perfectly when text is typed into the textarea, but not when a large amount of text is pasted in.

See fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/ynv6yta8/1/

And a snippet:

```js
// auto-expand/shrink text area
$('#mytextarea').bind('input propertychange paste', function() {
  var oldHeight = parseInt($(this).height());
  
  if (this.scrollHeight < 450) {
    $(this).height(0).height(this.scrollHeight);
  }
}).change();
```

```css
#mytextarea {
  height: 250px;
  width: 450px;
  min-height: 250px;
  min-width: 450px;
  resize: none;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="mytextarea"></textarea>
```

I didn't leave any debugging statements in the fiddle, but the event is indeed getting fired correctly on paste, but `this.scrollHeight` always evaluates to something around `250px`, even when the pasted text is very large. I guess `this.scrollHeight` hasn't been updated yet at the time the `paste` event is fired? How can I get around this?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem in Chrome 61, Firefox 56, or Safari 11.

Comment: Yep, your guess is correct, paste fires before the value has actually been changed. You can make the changes to the textarea in a delayed function, or use `input` event instead of all those you have. Notice, that `propertychange` (IE only?) leads to infinite loop very easily.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
$(document).on("input", "textarea", function()
{
   $(this).prop('style').cssText = 'height:auto;';
   $(this).prop('style').cssText = 'height:' + $(this).prop('scrollHeight') + 'px';
});
```

The Css:

```
textarea
{
    resize:none;
    max-height:450px;
    min-height:250px;
}
```

Inspired by https://codepen.io/vsync/pen/czgrf

jsfiddle:   [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/885x0cdt/2/)

Comment: Why is the line containing 'height:auto;' necessary? It works without that line.

Comment: It seems you are right, it works without that line. 

Comment: I take that back, without height:auto; the box expands and never contracts.
Try this Fiddle to get an idea. 
https://jsfiddle.net/TheKimster/3dvqrpty/1/